# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

please try and fix my problem i am using the Flask framework

```
@app.route("/",methods = ["GET","POST"])

def hello():

if request.method == "POST":

    text = request.form['txt']

    val  = m.predict_statement(text)

return render_template("index.html",values = val)
```

Comment: when the request verb is `GET` the if statement `if request.method == "POST":` is not executed so in `return render_template("index.html",values = val)` the val is not initilized and you get the error.

Comment: What happens if request method isn't "POST"?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to handle this would be.

```
@app.route("/",methods = ["GET","POST"])
def hello():

val = None

if request.method == "POST":

    text = request.form['txt']

    val  = m.predict_statement(text)

return render_template("index.html",values = val)
```

Then in the template, you could make an if block that if vall then do whatever you want it to.

```
{% if values %}
whatever code you want
{% endif %}
```